# Как можно собрать код на LUA так чтобы привязка была не по индексу а по названию кости в Gmod

Tags: lua

кто ни будь знает как можно переписать этот код так чтобы была привязка не по индексу а по названию кости в "ManipulateBoneScale"?

**Пример:**

```
util.AddNetworkString( 'headsize' )

net.Receive('headsize', function(len, ply)
    ply:ManipulateBoneScale(6, Vector(net.ReadVector()))
end)
```

чтобы вместо "6" можно было вписать название самой кости "ValveBiped.Bip01_Head1"

Буду очень признателен если кто то подскажет решение.